# random moving character on lcd

Tags: arduino, circuit

I bought a new LCD 16*2 and the last one worked very well with this code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>  
 LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);   

 void setup()
 { 
    analogWrite(6, 20);
     lcd.begin(16, 2);
  }  
     void loop()
 {  
     lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
     lcd.print("Hello Friends");
}
```

But now a new LCD doesn't work well with this code and show random character, these characters are moving fast on LCD like this:
[image: 1]

When I add `delayMiroseconds()` its works well and doesn't matter how many seconds it's delayed.
Can you help to remove the delay at the end of the code and what should I do to make this code works well like before?

Comment: Is it for sure necessary to write the text to the display more than once? What happens if you move the loop code to the setup()?

Comment: You should also set pin 6 to an output pin before you use analogWrite().  See here: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/pinmode/

Comment: @GRitchie "You do not need to call pinMode() to set the pin as an output before calling analogWrite()." from https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

Comment: Read datasheet.  If they behave differently, do you not wonder why?  Why do you assume this part should work like the last one you experimented with?

Comment: Is your issue related to the `analogWrite(6,` ... ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/solved-i-think-lcd-random-character-display-but-serial-output-fine/89605) on the Arduino forum, PWM is not suited to controlling the contrast of these LCD screens without a filter.

Try to add a 10K potentiometer to control the contrast.